# Using Xpath to Retrieve the Text Content of an Element

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath

Hello I am trying to read my xml document using xpath. I have been at it for few weeks now and just learning XML and VB but seems like I hit a road block. I tried a few different attempts at doing this and I have no problem displaying the XML file on a webpage using the xpathnavigator class. But then i needed to format into an html table so i took another route and just added the xmldatasource with a formview. So here is my code for that

```
<oriondata station='GiftShop'>
<meas name="GiftShopTime">2011/02/08 16:39:01</meas>
<meas name="GiftShopItemNumber">6</meas>
<meas name="GiftShopDuration">200</meas>
</oriondata>
```

The values I would like to grab are the date "2011/02/08 16:39:01" in this example and the number "6" and also the duration which is "200"

Not sure what I am doing wrong if i use the

```
<asp:Label ID="lblID" Runat="server" Text='<%# XPath("//oriondata/meas/@name") %>' /></b><br/>
```

That gives me "GiftShopTime" but not the actual time. Also if i just use this

```
<asp:Label ID="lblID" Runat="server" Text='<%# XPath(".") %>' />
</b><br/>
```

That gives me the current node from what I am reading but the current node when i do this happens to be the actual time

I just have not figured out a way to specify each of those names I thought this should work

```
Xpath("/oriondata/meas/name/@GiftShopTime")
```

but that displays nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your xpath needs to be changed to

```
Xpath("/oriondata/meas[@name='GiftShopTime']")
```

The syntax of this particular xpath means "give me the value of the element **meas** who is a child of **oriondata** and whose attribute **name** has the value **'GiftShopTime'** ".

Comment: I am sorry code is not in there i thought i had to use that to put my code in a box

Comment: Also do you mind giving me a small explanation on how you came to that answer please

Answer (score 1):

> So here is my code for that

```
    <oriondata station='GiftShop'>
      <meas name="GiftShopTime">2011/02/08 16:39:01</meas>
      <meas name="GiftShopItemNumber">6</meas>
      <meas name="GiftShopDuration">200</meas>
    </oriondata>
```

> The values I would like to grab are
>   the date "2011/02/08 16:39:01" in this
>   example and the number "6" and also
>   the duration which is "200"

**Use** (respectively):

```
/*/meas[@name='GiftShopTime']
/*/meas[@name='GiftShopItemNumber']
/*/meas[@name='GiftShopDuration']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: //oriondata/meas[@name='GiftShopTime']/textContents